# Android Full Screen Ad (Interstitial) Won't Show When Screen is Locked

Tags: android, admob

I'm new to Android development and I'm creating an Alarm app that includes ads. A logical place I wanted to include a full screen ad was immediately after the user dismisses an alarm.

The problem I'm encountering is that the user's lock screen is typically active when the alarm goes off.  My activity and UI are displaying fine because I'm using the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` flag but when I call `interstialAd.show()` the **lock screen pops up and the ad is hidden behind it.** This is a pretty awful user experience because there is no real indication that an Ad has been loaded until the next time he/she decides to unlock their phone at which point it simply appears out of nowhere.

**My code:**

I initialize the ad in my activity's `onCreate()` method:

```
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("free")) {
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.alarm_dismissed_interstitial_ad_id));

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // ad closed or finished so we're done here.
                Log.d(TAG, "onAdClosed: ad closed... finishing activity");
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                    finishAndRemoveTask();
                } else finish();
            }
        });
        if (!mAdLoadStarted) {
            requestNewInterstitial();
        }
    }
```

`requestNewInterstitial()`:

```
private void requestNewInterstitial(){
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    mAdLoadStarted = true;
}
```

I call the show method once the user has dismissed the alarm:

```
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("free")) {
        // The dismiss sequence has finished so we can display the full screen ad.
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDismissFinished: Ad wasn't displayed because it didn't load in time.");
        }
    }else{
        // No ads for the paid version, we're done here
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            finishAndRemoveTask();
        } else finish();
    }
```

Comment: You want to put ads on the lock screen? "This is a pretty awful user experience"

Comment: The entire experience typically occurs on the lock screen because this is an Alarm app so the phone is usually asleep when the alarm goes off. The user has to complete a set of activities to prove he is awake and dismiss the alarm. After dismissal, if he's using the free version of the app, he gets an ad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that `interstialAd.show()` creates a new window/activity without the `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED`.

You have to display the ad using a window that has this flag set too or in the same window you were displaying your content to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This would make sense with what I'm seeing but I'm not sure how to fix it. I've looked through the available InterstitialAd methods and couldn't find anything for setting Window Flags or anything to keep it from opening a new window...

Comment: Hmmm... maybe interstitial ad is not the right ad for you. Try maybe a regular AdView with FULL_WIDTH and AUTO_HEIGHT (as the AdSize) and display it in your own window.

Comment: By design, the Mobile Ads SDK locks down the Activity used to display interstitial ads pretty tightly, so I can't imagine there's any way to modify the window settings. Building on what @selalerer said, though, I'd suggest looking at Native Express, which can give you a custom, native ad presentation within your layout: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6270315